# Change date format when importing from CSV

Tags: python, excel, date, csv, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file where the date is formatted as `yy/mm/dd`, but Excel is reading it wrongly as `dd/mm/yyyy` (e.g. 8th September 2015 is read as 15th of September 2008).

I know how to change the format that Excel *outputs*, but how can I change the format it uses to interpret the CSV data?

I'd like to keep it to Excel if possible, but I could work with a Python program.

Comment: Keep it to Excel you say...? See [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) and [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 3. Import it properly

Use DATA, Get External Data, From Text and when the wizard prompts you choose the appropriate DMY combination (Step 3 of 3, Under Column data format, and Date).

Comment: good answer :) +1 this is really the right answer ... I just showed my excel newbness :P

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1. change the format excel reads in

**edit: a better method is suggested in the OP comments to accomplish this, I was not aware you could do that**

it(excel) uses your windows settings

so you can go to

Control Panel > Clock, Language, Region > (under Region and Language) change the date,time or number format

and enter the appropriate format

### Option 2. change the csv date format

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
with open("output.csv","wb") as fout:
    csv_out = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv.reader(open("input.csv","rb")):
        row[date_index] = parse(row[date_index]).strftime("%x")
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```